# android - Null body after JSON request from Foursquare

Tags: android, json, google-maps, retrofit, foursquare

I want to search for nearby venues and add a marker on every nearby venue on google maps. 
For this I use Foursquare API and Retrofit to make request to the server but the problem is that I receive a null body as a response.

These are the parameters that I need to pass in: https://developer.foursquare.com/start/search

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search
  ?client_id=CLIENT_ID
  &client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET
  &v=20130815
  &ll=40.7,-74
  &query=sushi
```

Base URL: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

```
.baseUrl("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search/")
```

The interface I use to request the JSON from:

```
public interface FoursquareService {
    @GET("venues/search")
    Call<List<FoursquarePlaces>> getAllVenues(@Query("client_id") String clientId,
                                              @Query("client_secret") String clientSecret,
                                              @Query("v") String date,
                                              @Query("ll") LatLng longitudeLatitude);
}
```

The class that I use to get parameters from the body of the JSON:

```
public class FoursquarePlaces {
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String category;
    private String longitude;
    private String latitude;
    private String address;

    public FoursquarePlaces() {
        this.name = "";
        this.city = "";
        this.setCategory("");
    }

    public void setCity(String city){
        if (city != null){
            this.city = city.replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)", "");
        }
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

The retrofit client:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

I am adding a marker on the locations that I get from the body of the JSON:

```
foursquareService = retrofit.create(FoursquareService.class);
        venuesLatLng = new LatLng(venuesLatitude, venuesLongitude);
        foursquareService.getAllVenues(Constants.FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_KEY,
                Constants.FOURSQUARE_CLIENT_SECRET, formatedDate, latLng).enqueue(new Callback<List<FoursquarePlaces>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<FoursquarePlaces>> call, Response<List<FoursquarePlaces>> response) {
               for (FoursquarePlaces place : response.body()) {
                   // I get the error here on response.body()
                    venuesLatitude = Integer.parseInt(place.getLatitude());
                    venuesLongitude = Integer.parseInt(place.getLongitude());
                    venuesMarker.position(venuesLatLng);
                    mMap.addMarker(venuesMarker);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<FoursquarePlaces>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

The error that I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
```

And if i evaluate the expression response.body() i get:

```
errorDetail":"ll must be of the form XX.XX,YY.YY (received lat\/lng: (46.7700381,23.551585))
```

But I don't understand because I have given it a LatLng type, why wouldn't that be good, and why I get an empty body as response from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service expects *`ll`* parameter in format *`XX.XX,YY.YY`*. When you use `LatLng` the service uses `LatLng.toString()` to format the parameter as `lat/lng: (46.7700381,23.55158)` which is unacceptable to service.

You can change your service to accept `String` for `ll` parameter:

```
public interface FoursquareService {
    @GET("venues/search")
    Call<List<FoursquarePlaces>> getAllVenues(@Query("client_id") String clientId,
                                              @Query("client_secret") String clientSecret,
                                              @Query("v") String date,
                                              @Query("ll") String longitudeLatitude); // <- here data type is changed
}
```

And, while invoking simply pass parameter as: `latLng.latitude + "," + latLng.longitude`